# Compressing data before sending

Tags: unix

I can copy the records from one server to another using the following command.

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -pPassWord db tbl_name | 
        mysql -h100.100.100.100 -uroot -pPassword other_db tbl_name
```

But is it possible to zip it up while sending the data? for e.g.

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -pPassWord db tbl_name | 
        gzip -cf | gunzip -c | 
        mysql -h100.100.100.100 -uroot -pPassword other_db tbl_name
```

and extract it on the other server to be executed using mysql command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.ducea.com/2006/10/28/compressing-mysqldump-output/) here's blog post that shows you how

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the data while transferring it, but not within the `mysqldump` command. You have to transfer the compressed data in an explicit step, e.g.:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -pPassWord db tbl_name | gzip |
   ssh 100.100.100.100 "gunzip | mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pPassWord db tbl_name"
```